# Using aggregate and window function within a sub-query

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a situation where I have a query with a sub-query that uses `SUM() OVER`.  While the sub-query works fine on its own, when used in-context of the outer query, the aggregation isn't applied.

I've made this test case to approximate what I'm trying to do:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TestNumbers
  (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, number INTEGER);
INSERT INTO TestNumbers (number)
  VALUES (10), (15), (20), (25), (30);

SELECT SUM(number) OVER (ORDER BY id) FROM TestNumbers;
```

This returns the expected result... a rolling sum of all values.  `10`, `25`, `45`, `70`, `100`.

However, if I use this as a sub-query...

```
SELECT (
  SELECT SUM(number) OVER (ORDER BY id)
) FROM TestNumbers;
```

I get a result with the aggregation not applied.  `10`, `15`, `20`, `25`, `30`.

How can I use this aggregation with the `OVER` in a sub-query?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You mention an `update`, but then the rest of the question is only `select`s.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah, sorry, I'm trying to break this down into the simplest reproducible form, but figured the reason for this needed at least a bit of explanation up top.  I think if I can get the `SELECT` with the inner `SELECT` working, I'll make that an `UPDATE` no problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Removed the confusing stuff about the `UPDATE`.  Thanks for checking out my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised that this even works:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(number) OVER (ORDER BY id))
FROM TestNumbers;
```

I mean, it does.  Basically, the subquery is correlated subquery, so it runs for each row in the outer query.  That is, there is just a single value for each run -- the correlated value from the outer query.  That is just going to return the number.

It is not clear what you really want to do.

When I first read the query, I thought it was:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT SUM(number) OVER (ORDER BY id))
      FROM TestNumbers
     ) tn
```

This is fine and works with the accumulated value.

Moving the `FROM` to the subquery:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(number) OVER (ORDER BY id))
        FROM TestNumbers
       )
```

Breaks the query because the subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  Yeah, the reason I was querying for a single value was that I'm trying to do an `UPDATE table SET col= ( /* subquery */)`, and this test was an approximation of what I was trying to do and simulated the problem I was having.  Unfortunately, the `FROM` in the subquery works but because I also need to set the table in the `UPDATE`, the outer query breaks the inner.  I will figure out a better example and post a new question.  Thank you for answering this one though!